# Laravel 4.2 won't remember Auth::login() nor Auth::attempt() as soon as different page is accessed

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

The code: http://laravel.io/bin/1YdYn#80-81,83

I have a 2-step register procedure. In the first step, the user enters firstname, email and password, these will be used for authentication. When that's enter, the data is stored in the user table and the user get redirected to step 2.

In this post method, the user is logged in like this:

```
Auth::attempt( ['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')], true )
```

Which works fine. So on step 2 it can say "Hi Kyle", for example. The user is logged in because I can do `Auth::user()->firstname`.

It works fine, LOCALLY.

On the production server, `Auth::check` is true immediately after filling out step 1 of the registration procedure, but as soon as the user press next to go to step 2, `Auth::check` results in FALSE. So I can't use `Auth::user()`.

I have no clue what the problem could be. The form is setup with Laravel's `Form::open()` and it adds a token in the form. The auth happens with email and password.

The only reason I can think of that it doesn't work on the server is because the app is on a subdomain and something gets messed up with the session, so the public dir of the Laravel app is accessed via  `http://myapp.domain.com`.

Steps to register are:

1. http://myapp.domain.com/join
2. http://myapp.domain.com/join/details -> Here the user is not logged in anymore on the server, eventhough I succesfully logged him in after step 1. Locally on my pc he still is logged on at the stage.

Anyone has a clue what could cause this? Any more info needed?

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'file',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => array(2, 100),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => false,

);
```

Regards,
Frank

Comment: Sounds like a session problem. What is your production session settings?

Comment: Make sure you have permission to write to the `app/storage` directory on your production server

Comment: I edited the question with some more info.

Comment: Are there any files in `app/storage/sessions` on your production server?

Comment: I emptied the folder, then did step 1 and submitted and 2 files appeared in the sessions folder.

Comment: Are you hosting on Heroku? I had a similar issue when hosting there.

Comment: Nope, not Heroku. I've now tried database as session driver, but still no result :(

Comment: Are you sure that in both steps you have exact the same domain? It should be in both case exactly the same (with or without www).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding to routes:

```
Route::get('set', function(){
    Session::put('session', 'works');
});

Route::get('get', function(){
    return Session::get('session');
});
```

then go to http://myapp.domain.com/set and http://myapp.domain.com/get . Does that display "works"?

And are you sure that the email/password you are trying to log in with exists in the database on the server?